# Ajax request returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, ajax-request

I have the following ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'../php/anmelden_info.php',
    data:{
        kat :  'Freizeitfussballer'
    },
    success: function(data){
        alert(data[0].anmelde_info);
    }
});
```

which alerts `undefined` but i don't know why, because when I go the my console and look for the answer I get:

```
[{"kategorien_id":"3","kat_name":"Fasnacht","anmelde_info":"\n<b>Informationen:.... ......<\/b>\n<br \/>\nDer Turniereinsatz betr\u00e4gt 100.- pro Mannschaft."}]
```

and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong!

Comment: Try to console.log(data) and use console to debug and see what exactly come in data object.

Comment: Before you try and access the data, do `data = JSON.parse(data)` and see if that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set `dataType: json` in you jquery call

As follows

```
 $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
     url:'../php/anmelden_info.php',
     data:{ kat :  'Freizeitfussballer'},
     dataType: json,
     success: function(data){
      console.dir(data);
     }
    });
```

or if it not worked try this

```
 $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
     url:'../php/anmelden_info.php',
     data:{ kat :  'Freizeitfussballer'},
     dataType: json,
     success: function(data){
     data = JSON.parse(data);
     console.dir(data);
     }
    });
```

Comment: Surely `dataType: "json",`

Answer (score 0):

```
Try the below code first whilst you have the developer tools open in either Firebug or Chrome.  This will show you the structure of the data obejct passed into the sucess method.

$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
     url:'../php/anmelden_info.php',
     data:{
      kat :  'Freizeitfussballer'
     },
     success: function(data){
      console.dir(data);
     }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `$.each()` in your success function:

```
success: function(data){
    $.each(data, function(i, item){
       console.log(data.anmelde_info);
    });
}
```

And i suggest you to use `console.log()` for a better debugging.